# How to export and use multiple custom modules in the same library with React Native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

So I have a React Native custom library that I made that has 2 modules made, `moduleA` and `moduleB`. How do I export them so that I can call both of the modules in my project?

Before when I had only one module it would work perfectly like this:

```
//Index.js file of my library

import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { moduleA } = NativeModules;
export default moduleA;
```

and then in my React native project I could call it like this

```
//Home.js file of my project

import moduleA from 'custom_library';
moduleA.method(); //Works fine
```

But now that I have two modules, I'm not sure how to change the modules and the import such that both can be used. Is it even possible? The end goal that I want to be able to do is

```
//Home.js file of my project
import { moduleA, moduleB } from 'custom_library';
moduleA.method();
moduleB.method();
```

Sorry for the basic question, but I'm getting frustrated that nothing I've tried is really working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `export` keyword. You will find more detailed examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/export).

#### index.js of custom_library

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { moduleA, moduleB } = NativeModules;
export { moduleA, moduleB };
```

#### home.js

```
import { moduleA, moduleB } from 'custom_library';
moduleA.method();
moduleB.method();
```

Comment: I'm sorry if i wasn't clear, but these are modules whose methods are defined natively in the iOS / Android code. It would be like this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Comment: @AlexanderQian, oh sorry I misunderstood. I updated my answer, have you tried this solution before?